# Picklist formula help

Tags: apex, formula

I'm trying to do validation for a values on a pick-list and a text field. I was thinking something like this.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( SAP_Transportation_Zone__c , "USA") && (Country__c != "US")true,false)
OR(
SAP_Transportation_Zone__c,"CANADA" &&(Country__c != "CA")true,false)
```

This will continue to grow with all of my countries and their acceptable SAP_Transportation_Zone__c, this is my first time really attempting a formula and not sure really how to go about it.  Something like this? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Formulas are limited to 5000 characters when compiled and you will likely run out with many countries/zones.  Explore putting your rules into a custom setting or sobject and use apex for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if this is no help, however IF there area limited number of Country Codes and relevant Transportation Zones, would it be useful to put them into a new object/table in SF (like a conversion table) and use a trigger to map them?

I'm still very much a newbie with apex so my apologies in advance if this is not the case!

Comment: You're right, that is what I did.. Works good I just had to write a trigger.

Comment: Just in this case I was trying to get away from having to make one

Comment: Thanks Eric - nice to know that I'm starting to get my head around some of the concepts. I've got lots to learn, and this site is so useful.

Comment: Well I will also add I took away the option for them to even make a mistake by creating a trigger that will auto populate the Transportation Zone by checking the country.

Answer (score 1):

If the `SAP_Transportation_Zone__c` field has ALWAYS the first 2 letters equal to the `Country__c` picklist, and also they're both required and should match, then you can do something like this I think:

```
IF(Country__c != LEFT(TEXT(SAP_Transportation_Zone__c), 2) , true, false)
```

So basically you get the first 2 letters from the transportation zone value and you make sure the country value matches. This way it's dynamic and will work for all values as long as the first 2 characters match.

For all the exclusions where the characters do not match, you can add an `OR` to the formula above.

Comment: Wow good idea, I will look into this further.

Comment: Initially I started writing the same comment as @crop1645 :) So if this doesn't work for you, you should be looking at writing a trigger

Comment: It doesn't work for every case.  I only have 224 countries though should I still hit a governor limit?

Comment: I recommend to find the cases that it doesn't work with and add them as additional formulas and use mine for the ones that match - guaranteed you won't hit the governor limit that way. I guess it's less than 20% of the fields that don't match...

Comment: Writing it your way, 1 line for each country - you'll hit the limits before you even get half way through. Conclusion - either my formula + exclusions or trigger for the whole thing.